# oracle 10g reports, ERROR: Failed to locate the browser Try connecting again

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oraclereports

I am using oracle reports 10 g on Windows 8, Forms are working just fine. But when I create a web report and click on run web layout the browser opens this URL (C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\docroot\MODULE2001C03476.htm) how can I make it open through this link `(http://mymachine:8889/reports/rwservlet?)`. Could you please tell me what's happening!?

any help?!

Answer (score 0):

This is because either the *directory/folder* where the browser `exe` resides
is not there or in the browserpath or browsername is not set properly in the `Software\ORACLE\Toolkit\TKBrowser\Browserpath`.

Also please see if REPORTS_TMP dir in registry `HKLM\Software\oracle\home<x>` points to a valid directory.

**For example:**

`hkey_current_user/software/oracle/toolkit/tkbrowser/browserpath` can be set to

```
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer
```

`hkey_current_user/software/oracle/toolkit/tkbrowser/browsername` can be set to

```
iexplore.exe
```

So if this does not work then try after making IE your default browser.

Comment: even though, still opening the web layout from this path (C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\docroot\MODULE2001C03476.htm) instead of this 'http://mymachine:8889/reports/rwservlet?'